# Mulit select widget post large data in form

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I am using XMultiSelects Widget to post large data in form.(Yii Framework)

```
<div class="row">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'list'); ?>
<div style="display: inline-block">
    <?php
    $this->widget('multiselects.XMultiSelects', array(
        'id' => 'hd-programs', //since there are multiple selector pairs on this page we need to set identifier
        'leftTitle' => 'Available',
        'leftName' => 'availableList',
        'leftList' => $availableList,
        'rightTitle' => 'Selected',
        'rightName' => get_class($model) . '[list][]',
        'rightList' => $list,
        'size' => 15,
        'width' => '350px',
    ));
    ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model, 'list'); ?>
       </div>
```

where $avaliableList is very large data set.

Now when i print value of form using print_r($_Post['MyFormName']) $list is not posted.
Any suggestion how could i handle large data with multiselect widget.